# Is there a "nice" inner model for $\mathsf{ZF}$ + a Dedekind-finite infinite set of reals?

Tags: set-theory, lo.logic, model-theory, axiom-of-choice, inner-model-theory

*Below, given a formula $\varphi$ which $\mathsf{ZF}$ proves defines a set of reals and an inner model $W$, I'll write "$\varphi^W$" and "$L(\varphi^W)$" for "$\{x:W\models\varphi(x)\}$" and "$L(\{x: W\models\varphi(x)\})$ respectively, and I'll suppress the superscript when $W=V$.*

Broadly speaking, I'm curious whether there is an inner model construction which plays an analogous role for $\mathsf{ZF}$ + "There is a Dedekind-finite infinite set of reals" that $L(\mathbb{R})$ does for $\mathsf{ZF+AD}$ - namely, that (assuming large cardinals!) it satisfies the relevant theory, is appropriately canonical and idempotent, and has a forcing-absolute theory.

Here's one way to make this precise. Say that a formula $\varphi$ is **anti-Dedekindian** iff the following are each provable in $\mathsf{ZFC+LC}$, where $\mathsf{LC}$ is some large cardinal hypothesis currently believed to be consistent *(if one wants a specific choice here, a proper class of Woodins seems natural but I'm happy to go higher)*:

1. $\varphi$ defines an infinite set of reals.
2. $L(\varphi)\models$ "$\{x:\varphi(x)\}$ is Dedekind-finite."
3. $\varphi^{L(\varphi)}=\varphi\cap L(\varphi)$ (so consequently $L(\varphi)^{L(\varphi)}=L(\varphi))$.
4. For every set-generic extension $V[G]$ and every sentence $\sigma$, in the notation above we have $$L(\varphi)\models\sigma\quad\iff\quad L(\varphi)^{V[G]}\models\sigma.$$ (Of course this is really a *scheme* of sentences, one for each $\sigma$.)

Even without condition (4) this seems difficult, so I'm also interested in **weakly anti-Dedekindian** formulas (= satisfying only (1)-(3) above).

> Question: is there a (weakly) anti-Dedekindian formula?

---

EDIT: Note that $(3)$, as far as I can tell, prevents tricks like "use $0^\sharp$ to build a canonical generic over $L$" - while this will be forcing-absolute and so satisfy $(4)$, we lose the relevant parameter (here $0^\sharp$) when we pass to the inner model and so $(3)$ breaks.

Comment: Are there any results of the form “no inner model…”?

Comment: @MattF. Sure! There are various inner model theoretic dichotomies (starting with Jensen's covering lemma) which can be thought of as saying that certain sorts of inner models don't exist. We also have analogues of Scott's theorem that certain large cardinals can't be witnessed in certain fine structural constructions (e.g. the eventual need for long extenders, if memory serves).

Comment: @MattF. Possibly more germanely (in that it treats "uniformly definable" inner models in a sense), see the discussion starting at the bottom of page 2 of Jensen/Steel's "[$K$ without the measurable](https://math.berkeley.edu/~steel/papers/knombljune2013.pdf)" re: the optimality of their result.

Comment: Now I have googled “no inner model” and find Gabe Goldberg saying “no inner model that is missing a real correctly computes $\omega_1$”. https://mathoverflow.net/a/366620/44143

Comment: @MattF. “no inner model that is missing a real correctly computes 1” *if* AD holds. There are also various results in a similar spirit: (1) if $0^\sharp$ exists, no inner model that misses $0^\sharp$ correctly computes $\omega_2$. (2) (Assuming choice), if MM holds, no inner model that misses a real correctly computes $\omega_2$. [In fact, correctly computing cardinals, and even just correctly computing $\omega_2$, imposes very strong restrictions on inner models. On the other hand, correctly computing $\omega_1$ (under choice) does not really give us much.]

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: (1) sounds a bit weird. Suppose that $\kappa_1,\kappa_2$ are $\omega_1^V$ and $\omega_2^V$. Then forcing over $L$ with $\operatorname{Col}(\omega,{<}\kappa_1)*\operatorname{Col}(\kappa_1,{<}\kappa_2)$ will not add $0^\#$, but will compute $\omega_2$ correctly. Maybe you meant $\aleph_\omega$?

Comment: @Asaf No, I mean $\omega_2$. DOI: 10.1017/jsl.2016.68

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: I see! There's no generic for that collapsing in $L[0^\#]$, and if there was, say that we were in $L[0^\#,r]$, where $r$ was a real collapsing $\omega_2^{L[0^\#]}$ to be countable, then we haven't computed $\omega_2^V$ correctly.